# How to add numbers in duplicate list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've collected data from txt file and made it to the list (actually there are a lot more players, so it is impossible to count without loop), like:

```
data_list = [
['FW', '1', 'Khan', '2', '0'], 
['FW', '25', 'Daniel', '0', '0'], 
['FW', '3', 'Daniel', '1', '0'], 
['FW', '32', 'Daniel', '0', '0'], 
['FW', '4', 'Khan', '1', '0']
]
```

and I want to add the goal of each Khan and Daniel and make a list like:

```
['Khan', 3]
['Daniel', 1]
```

I have a name list (`name_list = [Khan, Daniel]`)

I've tried to do with for loop, like:

```
goal = []
num = 0
for i in name_list:
        for j in data_list:
                if i == j[2]:
                        num += int(j[3])
                        goal.append([i, num])
                else:
                        continue
```

and it did not work. 
I am very novice, so your comments will be a really big help.
Thanks!

Comment: /wjandrea I fixed problems you pointed. actually I did not understand your solution

Comment: thanks for pointing problems... I was so idiot

Comment: and if it is not very hard, can you show how to use Counter thing in my problem? I did not understand by reading the page you linked.

Comment: Welcome. It happens to all of us at the start :) Sure, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Just use a counter, its a much more simpler and more efficient approach.  You can find many examples online but a good one would be something like this https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html

Comment: (FYI I cleaned up my comments that are no longer needed, and you can do the same.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother doing it manually. Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for j in data_list:
    name = j[2]
    goal = int(j[3])
    c[name] += goal

print(c.most_common())  # -> [('Khan', 3), ('Daniel', 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is very close from working, there are syntax error and one single real problem.

The problem is that you are appending `num` too soon. You should sum over rows that contain the name you are looking for, then, once all rows have been seen append the value:

```py
data_list = [
    ['pos', 'num', 'name', 'goal', 'assist'],
    ['FW', '1', 'Khan', '2', '0'], 
    ['FW', '25', 'Daniel', '0', '0'], 
    ['FW', '3', 'Daniel', '1', '0'], 
    ['FW', '32', 'Daniel', '0', '0'], 
    ['FW', '4', 'Khan', '1', '0']
]

name_list = ['Khan', 'Daniel']

goal = []
for name in name_list:
    total_score = 0
    for j in data_list:
        if name == j[2]:
            total_score += int(j[3])
    goal.append([i, total_score])
```

On the other hand this strategy is not the most efficient since for every name the code will iterate over all rows. You could (using [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) to store intermediate results) need a single look on each row, independently of the number of "names" you are looking for.

```py
name_list = {'Khan', 'Daniel'}

goal = dict()
for row in data_list:
    if row[2] in name_list:
        if not row[2] in goal:
            goal[row[2]] = 0
        goal[row[2]] += int(row[3])
```

Which set `goal` to `{'Khan': 3, 'Daniel': 1}`.

Yet this could be improved (readability), using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). What default dictionary do is doing the existence check of a given "key" and initialisation automatically for you, which simplifies the code:

```py
from collections import defaultdict 

goal = defaultdict(int)
for row in data_list:
    if row[2] in name_list:
        goal[row[2]] += int(row[3])
```

Which does the exact same thing as before. At that point it's not even clear that we really need to provide a list of names (unless memory is an issue). Getting a dictionary for all names would again simplify the code (we just need to make sure to ignore the first row using the slice notation `[1:]`):

```py
goal = defaultdict(int)
for row in data_list[1:]:
    goal[row[2]] += int(row[3])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary to keep the sum number of goals, with the names as keys. This will make easier to access the values:

```py
goals_dict = {}
for name in name_list:
    goals_dict[name] = 0
# {'Khan': 0, 'Daniel': 0}
```

Then just sum it:

```py
for name in name_list:
    for data in data_list:
        if data[2] == name:
            goals_dict[name] += int(data[3])
```

Now you will have your dictionary populated correctly. Now to set the result as the list you requested, do as such:

```py
result = [[key, value] for key, value in d.items()]
```

Comment: FWIW, a simpler initialization: `goals_dict = dict.fromkeys(name_list, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

In your above code you increment the value of `num` without first defining it. You'll want to initialize it to 0 outside of your inner for loop. You'd then append the name/goal to the list like this:

```
for i in name_list:
    #Init num
    num = 0
    # Iterate through each data entry
    for j in data_list:
        if i == j[2]:
            # Increment goal count for this player
            num+= int(j[3])
    # Append final count to goal list
    goal.append([i, num])
```

This should have the desired effect, although as @wjandrea has pointed out, a `Counter` would be a much cleaner implementation.